# How to merge previous commit on same branch?

Tags: git, git-merge

I made a commit few days ago with commit hash "ABC". After "ABC" commit, I have pushed several commits. But now I want to merge HEAD with "ABC" commit.

How can I merge any previous commit (using hash) from the same branch?

Comment: Do you want to apply this commit on some other branch or merge master onto this branch??

Comment: As the commit is merged already, merging it again would be no-op. Could you explain what you expect it to do?

Comment: We, 2 friends, are working on the same branch. I have removed his code during merge conflict and push several commits. Now, I want to merge with his previous commit. (I can use git cherry-pick to merge commit from another branch). But now I want to merge from the same branch. @ShubhamKhatri & max630

Answer (score 0):

If the number of files in which you removed your collaborator's changes be small, then the easiest thing to do might be to just manually diff those files in your IDE and bring back the deleted work.  Then, make a commit as a fix for this problem.  Merging with a previous commit might be a no-op, or might not work at all.

Comment: We, 2 friends, are working on the same branch. I have removed his code during merge conflict and push several commits. Now, I want to merge with his previous commit. ( I can use git cherry-pick to merge commit from another branch). But now I want to merge from the same branch.

Comment: @HasanulIslam I would then recommend that you just manually open each file in question in your IDE, and compare against the commit immediately before you removed the code.  Then, bring in that deleted code and make a commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cherry-pick`

```
git checkout your_branch
git cherry-pick <ABC>
```

Comment: I have used cherry-pick to merge commit from another branch. Does it work from the same branch?

Comment: @HasanulIslam No, `cherry-pick` is used for merging commit(s) form other branch. If you want to merge code from same branch, you can try `git rebase -i HEAD~n` (replace `n` with the number you need) to sort/squash commit.

Comment: If the commit was created long ago, how can I find the value of n? @Iridium Cao

Comment: Hi @HasanulIslam , can you draw a diagram of your git tree, that's will be helpful.

Comment: Suppose each combination of 3 character defines a commit hash on same branch. i.e. aaa -> aab -> aac -> ... ->zzz , zzz is HEAD, I want to merge zzz with aab.